# Specifiy output direction for connexion point

Tags: visio

I have to work with Visio and I don't understand how I can specify the output direction for a shape connexion point (blue star).

As you can see on this picture. Visio doesn't want me to make a straight connexion from the triangle shape to the square one. It seems the connexion is only authorized on a vertical vertical direction.

[image: issue]

Of course I can manually readjust the bad track afterwards but if I decide to move any of the shapes the connexion become wrong again.

I would like to know how to specify the output direction for shape's connexion points?

Comment: You can look in the shapesheet for the shape in the connection points list, I know you can set a vector for the direction of the connection, but I'm not sure changing that will fix your problem or not.  I don't know if there's any UI in Visio for doing this, beyond the shapesheet..

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't have access to such option :(

Comment: You have to put Visio into Developer Mode to access the shapesheet, assuming you didn't do that...